# Secure two-way communication between client and server including large file attachments

Tags: .net, web-services, sockets, remoting, data-transfer

In .net, I need to securely transfer files 4mb in size from client machines running my software to a central server, process, and securely send back results consisting of a pdf file, a jpg image, and xml data.

What .net technology would be most appropriate for this? (web service. remoting, etc)

Answer (score 3):

WCF- If it is .NET to .NET (like it sounds like it is), then you should use WCF with TCPBinding. There are [lots of good examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751514.aspx) here to get you started. You might want to [consider streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) if scalability is a concern.

If you want to host in IIS (then you can't use TCP- but consider WAS), make sure you [use MTOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889.aspx). If you're still unsure as to which binding to use, then have a look at [this binding decision diagram](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/10/02/choosing-the-right-wcf-binding.aspx).

WCF has a [lots of security options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx) for you to consider. You will find the [Patterns and Practises- WCF Security Guidance](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurity) useful for this.

Please note that ASMX Webservices and remoting are now considered legacy- WCF is the way forward.

Update- If your operating system supports it, then you may wish to [consider using WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx).

Comment: Only if you consider WAS as being IIS, which I don't as WAS is available without IIS being installed.

Comment: The point was 'You can use TCP with IIS'.
WAS is not IIS but it sure brings ability to host non-HTTP services in it.

Comment: @Dmitry- thanks- I thought I had mentioned WAS in my answer, but I hadn't. I've now updated it.